# React Pagination how change data with page number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

i have a list in my react project which working with local data. So i keep and update my data with state.

I need to show on list page 5 post per page. And i'm using this plugin for pagination.

https://github.com/vayser/react-js-pagination/issues

```
{data &&
        data?.map((item, i) => (
          <React.Fragment key={i}>
            <Item item={item} index={i} />
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      <Pagination
        activePage={activePage}
        itemsCountPerPage={5}
        totalItemsCount={data ? data.length : 1}
        pageRangeDisplayed={5}
        onChange={handlePageChange}
        itemClass="page-item"
        linkClass="page-link"
      />
```

Everything works well. I can display pagination. I can display page size according with my data.
I can set active page when click to page number.

```
const handlePageChange = (pageNumber: number) => {
    setActivePage(pageNumber);
  };
```

but how change data according to pagination? so when click to second page i wan't to show second 5 item of my data

Comment: You could store the `activePage` value in state and display the corresponding page data based on that. You'd need to map from the `activePage` value to your corresponding page data. This could be an index in an array or a mapping to a unique id value.
What does the page data look like that you're hoping to display?

Comment: its like data = [{name: "A", score: 1}, {name: "B", score: 13}] yes i have the. active page i can access it but i didn't understand where and how i will modified my data based. on active page

Comment: In your case the `activePage` could correlate to the index of the current page. So in your render function you'd only render the element in the array whose index matches the `activePage` value.